# Expected value of X given its p.m.f and $Y=X^2-1$

Tags: statistics, expectation

$X$ is a discrete random variable with p.m.f $$p(x)=\frac{|x|}{20}$$ for $x = -4, -3, ..., 3, 4$ and $0$ otherwise. I was also given $Y=X^2-1$.

Now I need to find $E(X)$. So, is $Y=X^2-1$ not important in this case?

If so, I tried:

$$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{4} p(x_i)x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{4}\frac{|x_i|x_i}{20}$$

Or should $i$ start from $-4$?

EDIT: Final answer should be $0$ if starting from $-4$?

Comment: You should start at -4. $E(x)=\sum\limits_{x=-4}^{4} p(x)\cdot x=\sum\limits_{x=-4}^{4}\frac{|x|\cdot x}{20}$

Comment: But it is more useful to calculate $E(X^2)=\sum\limits_{x=-4}^{4} p(x)\cdot x^2=\sum\limits_{x=-4}^{4}\frac{|x|\cdot x^2}{20}$ since $E(Y)=E(X^2+1)=E(X^2)+1$

Comment: Are you sure that the question asks for $E(X)$, not $E(Y)$?  If you are sure, then yes, $y=x^2+1$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Your edit is right, $E(X)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the PDF $p(x) = |x|/20,$ for $x = -4, -3, \dots, 4.$
(PDF is alternate terminology for PMF.)

[image]

You can see that the 'balance point' of the PDF is $0$ so you ought to get
$$E(X) = \sum_{\text{all } x}xp(x) = \sum_{x=-4}^4 x\frac{|x|}{20} = 0.$$
The actual computation is
$\mu_x=E(X) = (-0.80) + (-0.45) + (-0.20) + (-0.05) +  0 +  0.05 + 0.20 + 0.45 + 0.80 = 0.$

That finishes one part of the problem, but I think there are other parts
worth exploring. If you have not yet seen the ideas involved, I predict you
will see them in your course soon.

---

**Variance of a discrete random variable.** You can also find
$$E(X^2) = \sum_{x= -4}^4 x^2\frac{|x|}{20} = 3.20 +1.35+ 0.40 +0.05+ 0+ 0.05+ 0.40 +1.35 +3.20 = 10.$$

Then you could find $$Var(X) = \sum_{x=-4}^4 (x-\mu_x)^2p(x) = E(X^2) - \mu_x^2 = 10,$$
where I will let you fill in the details.

**Function of a discrete random variable.** You also mention the random variable $Y.$
The values of $Y = X^2 - 1$ are shown in the table below:

```
 x    y   Prob
-------------------
-4   15   4/20
-3    8   3/20
-2    3   2/20
-1    0   1/20
 0   -1    0
 1    0   1/20
 2    3   2/20
 3    8   3/20
 4   15   4/20
```

Then the possible values of $Y$ are $0, 3, 8,$ and $15,$ where $-1$ is
omitted because it has probability $0.$ The respective probabilities are

$P(Y = 0) = 2/20,\, P(Y=3) = 4/20,\, P(Y=8) = 6/20,$ and
$P(Y = 15) = 8/20.$ Notice that $2/20 + 4/20 + 6/20 + 8/20 = 20/20 = 1$
which must be true for the probabilities in a distribution.
So the PDF of $Y$ is given by the following table:

```
      y:   0    3    8   15   
 P(Y=y):  .1   .2   .3   .4
```

Now, there are two ways in which to find $E(Y):$ First, in terms of $X$
as $$E(Y) = E(X^2 - 1) = E(X^2) - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9.$$

Second, using the distribution of $Y$ just derived:
$$E(Y) = 0(1/10) + 3(2/10) + 8(3/10) + 15(4/10) = 90/10 = 9.$$

Finally, here is a plot of the distribution of $Y.$

[image]